# Statistics counter based on user role

Tags: nodes, 9

I need to track some basic usage statistics for a subset of my authenticated user roles in Drupal 9.

Is there a way to make the core statistics counter only count node views based on user roles? The three counters it provides are all I need, I just need them to only record certain user roles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statistics module adds a js library to the node build. You can remove it if you don't want to count the node:

*mymodule.module*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter() for node entities.
 */
function mymodule_node_view_alter(array &$build) {
  $roles = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
  if (!in_array('special_role', $roles)) {
    if (isset($build['#attached']['library'])) {
      $key = array_search('statistics/drupal.statistics', $build['#attached']['library']);
      if ($key !== FALSE) {
        unset($build['#attached']['library'][$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This only works if the roles are altering permissions. If not, add a cache context for the user roles:

```
$build['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user.roles';
```

Comment: That looks perfect thank you. I'm afraid I don't understand this line though `This only works if the roles are altering permissions.` could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Normally every role has a different set of permissions. But you could create multiple roles with the same permissions and then use them to control things not directly connected to permissions, like here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm even more confused now. The snippet makes sense; it removes the statistics js library if the user doesn't have the correct role. Why does the cache context matter here? I don't plan on changing user roles, Or is the same modified node getting presented to multiple users?

Comment: Yes, exactly. By default, the cached node is presented to any user having the same permissions.

Comment: That is somewhat counter-intuitive to me but does explain some odd behavior with user roles I've run into before...